# How to set a rate limit with express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a website built with React, of which users will have to fill up a form and press a submit button. The form inputs would then be stored in our database(mongoDB). However, one common problem would be that if the user clicks the submit button multiple times, the information would be sent to the database multiple times. I am trying to set a limit at the route where the information gets posted to the db.

I have tried using express-rate-limit and removing the express.router(just used app = express()) but it doesn't seem to work. I set the limit to 1 request within a minute, but when I click submit twice, my information still gets posted to the db twice.

This is my code on the front end to upload to database

```
uploadDatabaseHandler = async() =>{
    await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/users", this.state).then(() => {
      console.log("Client: Uploaded user information to Database")
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

This is my code on the back end. Ideally if I would want to stick to express router but how should I implement a limiter?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

router.post('/users', (req,res) => {
   ...
})
```

This was what I tried when I removed router. But still didn't work.

```
const app = express();

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 1 // limit each IP to 1 requests per windowMs
});

//  apply to all requests
app.use(limiter);

app.post('/users', (req,res) => {
   ...
})
```

Comment: A user accidentally clicking a button twice can be addressed in the interface fairly easily by just debouncing the submit process.

Comment: Are you already using express-session?  Is there a user login?  If so, it's better to use that as the key than the IP address because multiple users behind a corporate proxy or NAT may appear to be the same IP address.  Are you just trying to protect against things that a user might do in the actual web user interface from a browser?  Or are you trying to protect against programmatic attacks too?

Comment: Your configuration would allow each user one request to your entire server every 15 minutes.  If implemented properly, that prevents basic navigation.  You presumably want to rate limit only certain routes.

Comment: why not just handle this on the front-end? as soon as user submits disable submit functionality and clear form